# Can't connect to MySQL: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-8.0

I am using MYSQL Ver 8.0.20 for macos10.15 on x86_64. I have used the MySQL server many times, but now I can't connect to this anymore with a command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Error appears:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)
```

I've looked through all StackOverflow forum with similar problems, but nothing helped me yet.

Firstly, I checked MySQL Pane in the system settings, and it keeps showing me that the server is Off, even after starting it.

Then I tried it to launch manually with a command:

```
mysql start
```

Error appears:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)

Then with

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

It writes to me that the server started to work, and I checked it with

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

And it is really working, but I can't still connect to it. I look in /tmp folder and the file mysql.sock exists in it, and it has all relevant permissions:

```
srwxrwxrwx  1 _mysql   wheel      0  3 мар 13:33 mysql.sock

srwxrwxrwx  1 _mysql   wheel      0  3 мар 13:33 mysqlx.sock
```

How I can fix it? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: have a look at the control panel to see if the service is running. This error is because the server cannot start

Comment: @LelioFaieta, maybe, but how could I start the server then.

Comment: I would recommend checking /var/log/mysql/ files and seeing there are any kind of errors being reported. It does sound like the server isn't starting properly

Comment: @Jimmy, I've looked inside in logs in /usr/local/mysql/data/UserName.local.err. And there is error: [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:3344:for_table || ref_table thread 12      3145397850112

Comment: Then you should close this question or repurpose it, as that's the root of your problem ;)